# How do I typeset a syntax?

Tags: floats, typography

How can I typeset something like the following:

[image: Program Syntax]

It is similar to a BNF syntax but the more mathematical notation than the terminal symbols. Additionally I want to have the same textual description column right next to it.

I have no idea where to start, are there any packages for this?

Comment: What part do you need to be helped with? I don't see any exotic typeface here. Do you struggle with the way to align everything? One way to achieve that is to use `tabto` package, or a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ccp{2cm}p{4cm}}
        $\ell$  &   ::=     &       &   \textbf{Locations} \\
            &   $\vert$         &   $\tilde{\ell}$  &   abstract location \\
            &   $\vert$         &   $\ell_j$    &   concrete location \\
             
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Oh, i never thought about using tables for this, thank you :)